# AttributeError "truncate"

Tags: python, truncate, attributeerror

I am new to Python and I am trying to figure out a few things. I am running the following code where I created two functions to open and erase files.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

def erase(text):
    print open(text, "w")
    text.truncate()

piece = filename

print "here I am erasing it"
print erase(piece)
```

The file actually gets erased, but I get an error:

```
AttributeError: "str" object has no attribute to "truncate".
```

The file that I am importing exists and has strings in it. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
def erase(text):
    print open(text, "w")
    text.truncate()
```

In that function `text` is the filename, a string. So after printing out the file object that is returned by `open()`, you then call `truncate()` on the filename instead of the file object.

You have to store the return value of `open()` in a variable and then call `truncate()` on that object instead.

Or even better, use a `with` statement:

```
def erase(filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.truncate()
```

As Rob pointed out in the comments, the open mode `w` already truncates the file, so after opening it, you don’t actually need to do anything:

```
def erase(filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        pass
```

Comment: No need to truncate anything. When you use open(..., 'w'), it will already truncate the file.